# Sending attachment with sp_send_dbmail getting error Failed to initialize sqlcmd library with error number -2147467259

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sqlcmd

I am trying to test sending an attachment in SQL with the code below. I get an error -Failed to initialize sqlcmd library with error number -2147467259. Sending emails works just fine, only when adding the @query do I start getting this error. What am I missing?

```
DECLARE @query nvarchar(max) = 'select top (1) * from employees';
EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail
@profile_name = 'Email',
@recipients = 'me@gmail.com',
@query = @query,                     
@query_attachment_filename = 'employees.csv',      
@body_format = 'HTML',
@subject = 'Test';
```

Comment: Unless I recall incorrectly, I'm pretty sure that queries within a call to `sp_send_dbmail`, using the `@query` parameter, are run in the context of `msdb`, and I doubt your table `employees` exists in `msdb`. Try using 3 part naming in the query you pass for the `@query` parameter.

Comment: Also, don't forget to add an `ORDER BY` to your query too; otherwise you'll likely get inconsistent results as an arbitrary row will be returned each time the query is run, and SQL Server is under no obligation for that row to be the same row every time you run said query.

Comment: That was it!! Needed 3 part. Thanks a bunch.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Queries run using the `@query` parameter for `sp_send_dbmail` are run in the context of `msdb`. This means that for your query, you are effectively trying to reference an object `msdb.dbo.employees`. This object is unlikely to exist in `msdb`, as it is a system database (and if it does, I would suggest moving it), and as the object doesn't exist the query fails to parse and `sp_send_dbmail` generates an error.

To fix the problem, use 3 part naming in the query you define for the `@query` parameter:

```sql
DECLARE @query nvarchar(MAX) = N'SELECT TOP (1) * FROM YOurDatabase.dbo.employees ORDER BY YourColumn;'; --Replace values as needed
EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail
@profile_name = 'Email',
@recipients = 'me@gmail.com',
@query = @query,                     
@query_attachment_filename = 'employees.csv',      
@body_format = 'HTML',
@subject = 'Test';
```

Comment: or use the `@execute_query_database` parameter